# TASK_RUNNING process state

Tags: process, linux-kernel

I am reading "Linux Kernel Development". It has definition about "TASK_RUNNING"

**"TASK_RUNNING—The process is runnable; it is either currently running or on a runqueue waiting to run**". My question is why don't we have two separate state for "currently running" and "on a runqueue waiting to run". Like TASK__RUNNING and TASK_READYTORUN.

1) because when I first look at word "TASK_RUNNING", I thought it just refers to a running process state
2)  more exact definition would avoid many troubles

So do we have strong reasons not to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is **runnable**.

Futher state separation has no sence from the view of users of this field.

Because users of that state are not interact with a scheduler, knowing whether a process is scheduled or not is *useless*: immediately after you obtain that knowledge, the scheduler may change that property, so your knowledge becomes invalid.

---

As for name `TASK_RUNNING`, only Linux developers knows why it is choosen. It could be historic reason, or intentionally: "Think of the process as if it is **running**."